# Problema con script para mover archivos

Tags: windows, cmd, script, batch, windows10

estoy intentando crear un script (cmd) en Windows para **mover** archivos de cualquier tipo de extensión de una carpeta a otra pero me está dando problema tras problema, cada vez que lo ejecuto me da el error "No se puede encontrar la ruta especificada", he probado ya de todo pero no sé dónde fallo, aquí os dejo el script que llevo hasta ahora:

```
:============================|
: Script para mover archivos |
:============================|


    @echo off
    cls
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    set /p tipo="¿Que tipo de archivos desea copiar? Introduzca su extension..."
    echo Usted quiere mover los archivos de tipo ".%tipo%"

    echo.
    set /p origen="Introduzca la ruta de origen..."
    echo La ruta de origen seleccionada ha sido: %origen%

    echo.
    set /p destino="Introduzca la ruta de destino..."
    echo Sus archivos se copiaran en el siguiente destino: %destino%

    echo.
    for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b "%origen%"^|find ".%tipo%"') do (
     echo Moviendo:
     echo.
     echo %%a
     move "%%a" "%destino%"

    )

    echo.
    echo Sus archivos se han movido correctamente.
    timeout /t 5

    echo.
    echo Gracias por usar mi script.
    pause >nul
```

Comment: Pregunta... cuando agregas la direccion de la ruta, como la estan agregando? o si estas asignando un path antes de la direccion?

Por ejemplo
Path = C:\Users\

Luego la ruta
Path + %origen%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba así, debería funcionar (me ha costado varias ediciones para tocar lo menos posible tu script ;-) ):

```
:============================|
: Script para mover archivos |
:============================|


    @echo off
    set /p tipo=¨Qu‚ tipo de archivos desea copiar? Introduzca su extensi¢n: 
    echo Usted quiere mover los archivos de tipo ".%tipo%"

    echo.
    set /p origen=Introduzca la ruta de origen: 
    echo La ruta de origen seleccionada ha sido: %origen%

    echo.
    set /p destino=Introduzca la ruta de destino: 
    echo Sus archivos se copiar n en el siguiente destino: %destino%

    echo.
    for %%a in ("%origen%\*.%tipo%") do (
     echo Moviendo:
     echo.
     echo %%a
     move "%%a" "%destino%"

    )

    echo.
    echo Sus archivos se han movido correctamente.
    timeout /t 5

    echo.
    echo Gracias por usar mi script.
    pause >nul
```

Para la á acentuada de "Sus archivos se copiar n en el siguiente destino" abre una ventana de comandos y escribe echo á> a.txt. Abre a.txt, copia el primer carácter (invisible) y pégalo en tu archivo.
También puedes cambiar la línea echo %%a antes del comando move por echo %%~nxa para no mostrar toda la ruta de los archivos.

Comment: añade por favor la explicación de tu código

Comment: Es el mismo script de relyx (para mover archivos de la extensión que el usuario especifique) solo que con el comando original que no funciona corregido de manera que sí funcione.